# How can I make an object move in a direction efficiently?

Tags: java, performance, game-physics

Is there any way to efficiently move an object from point A to point B without having to use an inefficient `While(true)` loop? I tried to repaint Draw class, but it did not help with the performance issues. I am unable to trace the root of the huge performance issue. I tried to research moving entities on Google, GitHub, and others and found nothing useful. Any help is appreciated!

Code:

```
class Draw extends JPanel {

public static int x;
public static int y;

public static int randx;
public static int randy;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    BufferedImage image = null;
    BufferedImage image1 = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("Small Sheep Icon.png"));
        image1 = ImageIO.read(new File("Small Sheep Icon.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
    g.drawImage(image1, randx, randy, null);
    // g.drawString("Hello, World", x, y);
}
```

}

```
public static void sheepmove() {
    double starttime = System.nanoTime();
    double previoustime = 0;
    double waittime = 0;
    boolean xright = true;
    boolean waitswitch = false;
    int counter = 0;
    while(true) {
        double elapsedtime = (System.nanoTime() - starttime)/(1000000000);
        if (elapsedtime-waittime >= 1 || waitswitch == false) {
            if (waitswitch == true) {
                waitswitch = false;
            }
            waittime = elapsedtime;
            if (elapsedtime >= previoustime + 0.1) {
                previoustime = elapsedtime;
                if (xright == true) {
                    Draw.randx += 1;
                } 
                
                if (Draw.randx - 200 >= 50) {
                    if (counter == 0) {
                        waitswitch = true;
                        xright = false; 
                    }       
                    // System.out.println("Moving south...");
                    Draw.randy += 1;
                    if (Draw.randy >= 300) {
                        Draw.randy -= 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }
                frame.repaint();
                // System.out.print("=");
                // System.out.println("Previous Time: " + previoustime);
            }
        }
        
        
        // System.out.println(elapsedtime);
        // Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Demo();
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    // System.out.println("Mouse Moved!");
    Draw.x = e.getX();
    Draw.y = e.getY();
    frame.repaint();

}
```

Comment: Don't use a while loop. Use javax.swing.Timer and do you move increments there (plus replaint)

Comment: Where is `sheepmove` called? How many times is it called?